# VBA code to find value based on seek value

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I want to write a piece of VBA CODE that will goal seek the variable value into the static value based on the input value

[image: Excel1]
!

ie. something along these lines but i manually did these,

[image: Excel1]
!

Comment: Could you specify how does the formula work? Care to share your code & the formula to your post, please?

Comment: this is a hypothetical example to make things more simply, but the variable value is found my multiplying the variable value by 23. The aim is to get the variable value to be the same as the static value. Is there a way to attach a sheet to a post, if so i can include it without any vba code cause i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 3):

OK, here is what you have to do. First, you set the layout of your worksheet looks like this:

[image]

Here I use **Sheet1**. Please make changes accordingly if necessary.

In order to use Solver add-in, you must first make sure that the add-in is installed. For Office 2013 and later:

1. Click the **File** tab, and then click **Options** below the Excel tab.
2. In the **Excel Options** dialog box, click **Add-Ins**.
3. In the **Manage** drop-down box, select **Excel Add-ins**, and then click **Go**.
4. In the **Add-Ins** dialog box, select **Solver Add-in**, and then click **OK**.

After that, you must set a reference to the add-in in the workbook containing the code Visual Basic Editor (VBE) that calls the add-in's procedures. Click **References** on the **Tools** menu (see pictures below), and then select Solver under **Available References**.

[image]
[image]

Now, go to worksheet 1 code module in VBE. Just click **Sheet1** twice in VBE and paste the following code into it:

[image]

```
Sub VBASolver()
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$F$2", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$2:$B$4"
SolverSolve True
End Sub
```

You can  run the loaded VBA program by clicking **Run** icon below **Debug** menu or pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> key on the keyboard.

Comment: @user1448093 Please have a look these two links: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: @MLind Thank you. BTW, your answer was good, too. But why did you delete it? Just edit, no need to delete it

Comment: Thanks! My answer was in a short but not very intelligeble way pointing to the very same answer that you posted. Only that your answer made it perfectly clear and easy to follow making mine redundant.