# Find XValue or Value from point object

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a better (prettier) way of finding out the XValue in a series for a selected point. The point is selected by the user (by clicking) and thus the index in not known. The current method loops through each point and compares the names which is not very elegant since the names can in theory be the same for two different points.

The XValues are dates, and there are two types of charts. Eiether the series name is a date that is found in the data-table or the point XValue is a date that is found in the data table. The code below is from a Class Module. When data in the chart is selected the corresponding line in the data-table should also be selected.

```
Option Explicit
' Declare object of type "Chart" with events
Public WithEvents EvtChart As Chart
Private Sub EvtChart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
    Dim d As Date, r As Range
    If TypeOf Selection Is Series And IsDate(Selection.Name) Then
        d = CDate(Selection.Name)
    ElseIf TypeOf Selection Is Point Then
        If IsDate(Selection.Parent.Name) Then
            d = CDate(Selection.Parent.Name)
        Else
            Dim s As Series, p As Point, i As Long
            Set s = Selection.Parent
            Set p = Selection
            For i = 1 To s.Points.Count
                If p.Name = s.Points(i).Name Then
                    d = s.XValues(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set r = Range(Summary.Cells(HROW + 2, 1), Summary.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(d, , xlFormulas)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you include pictures of set instructions and convey your request with those pictures?

Comment: I don't understand your question. This is the whole code except the one that adds this event to a chart: Dim clsEventChart As New CEventChart
 Sub InitEvents()
    
    Set clsEventChart.EvtChart = Summary.ChartObjects("DynChart").Chart

End Sub

Comment: Try to post your question [like this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38949184/3397819)

Comment: A don't see the point. In my opinion the question is fully described as "help be get the XValue from a point object without knowing it's index number".

Comment: I have a working code. I just want to make it more elegant (and hopefully learn something from it).

Comment: Have you ever tried to understand what you have in the event procedure with `ElementID`, `Arg1` and `Arg2`? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192964.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703967/get-x-axis-value-on-the-click-of-chart-excel-vba

Comment: You've got it @AxelRichter! After checking is seems that ElementID returns xlSeries (=3) regardless if a whole series or a point is selected. Arg1 seems to return the SeriesIndex and Arg2 seems to return the PointIndex. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alexricher pointed out in his comment, the Arg2 gives the index needed. The revised code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
' Declare object of type "Chart" with events
Public WithEvents EvtChart As Chart
Private Sub EvtChart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
    Dim d As Date, r As Range
    If TypeOf Selection Is Series Then
        If IsDate(Selection.Name) Then d = CDate(Selection.Name)
    ElseIf TypeOf Selection Is Point Then
        If IsDate(Selection.Parent.Name) Then
            d = CDate(Selection.Parent.Name)
        Else
            Dim s As Series
            Set s = Selection.Parent
            d = s.XValues(Arg2)
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set r = Range(Summary.Cells(HROW + 2, 1), Summary.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(d, , xlFormulas)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

I also made a small correction in the `If TypeOf Selection Is Series Then` line that avoids run-time error if another chart element (such as the axis) is selected.